# Конфиденциальность в Google Play Market

Tags: google-play

Кто загружал когда-нибудь свои приложения в гугл плей маркет, расскажите, нигде не могу найти инфу, какая информация доступна разработчикам. Вот если я пишу отзыв, видно ли, какая модель моего телефона или логин моей почты, либо же виден только мой отзыв и мое имя? Когда я устанавливаю приложение, видно ли с какой почты (логин) установили? Про ip и др. конфиденциальные данные, которые розняться для разных прилодений, я не спрашиваю. Только те два вопроса. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Видно:

1. Имя фамилия
2. Время отзыва
3. почту **НЕ** видно
4. а также:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если маленькое исключение, что если один и тот же пользователь скачал одно и тоже приложение на разные устройства, то в разделе Устройство будет стоять прочерк. Например: "Устройство: - "